# Why there is no return value?

Tags: c, return, return-value

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int n) 
{
    if (n == 1 || n == 0) { return 0; }
    for (int i=2; i <= n/2; i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 2;
    isPrime(n);
    return 0;
}
```

I try to run my program, but there is none of return value. Why and how can i fix this?

Comment: It's returned. But you wrote code that discards it. What would like to happen with the value?

Comment: If you want to know what `isPrime` returned, you need to print the result.

Comment: You're not *using* the return value of `isPrime` anywhere - you could do something like `if ( isPrime(n) ) printf( "%d is prime\n", n ); else printf( "%d is not prime\n ");` (or, more compactly, `printf( "%d is%s prime\n", n, isPrime(n) ? "" : " not" );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is not a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). It will only print what you explicitly tell it to print:

```c
printf("%d\n", isPrime(n));
```

In the context of `main()` you could also `return`<sup>1</sup> that and check in the shell:

```c
return isPrime(n);
```

Where then you can do:

```bash
./isprime && echo "Is prime!"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Keep in mind this works *only* for `int` return values, and that `0` means success or in C parlance: "No error".

Comment: Most shells look at the return code as "truthy" in `&&` if it's 0. The shell example will print the reverse condition..

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah, forgot to invert there.